# Fetching the mongodb document taking too long

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mern

I have a project based on MERN stack, in which after giving the quiz based on the score 10 different documents are fetched from mongodb collection. There are total 2000 documents in mongodb collection.
While fetching its taking too long rather documents are not loading a loader rotates. How to resolve this?
The indexing I am doing on _id as this is only unique.

```
{"code": "80",
        "number": "3",
        "intro": "intro of",
        "education": "education details",
        "training": "training of exam",
        "scope": "scope of exam",
        "career_name":"XII Exam",
        "career_img" :"images/marine.jpg",
        "abilities": "Loreupm ipsun",
        "salary_global":"$90000",
        "work_styles":"Loerum ipsum "}


const { repo } = useSelector((state) => state.rep);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!repo) {
      dispatch(fetchRepo(history));
    }  
  }); 

 return (
        
            <>
             <Container maxwidth="sm" component="main" sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 2, flexGrow: 1 }}> 
  
              <Grid container spacing={3} direction="row" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" display="flex">
              <Fragment>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={6} sm={6}  alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
          <Card  sx={{ bgcolor: "#f7f7f7"}} elevation={4} alignItems="center">
          <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="194"
        image={repo[2].career_img}
        alt="Home Page"
        />
        <CardContent><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: repo[2].career_name }}></div></CardContent>
           </Card>
  </Grid>
  
  
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} sx={{flexGrow:1}}>
  <Card  sx={{ bgcolor: "#f7f7f7"}} elevation={4}>
           <CardContent> <><Typography sx={{textAlign:'center'}}>Introduction </Typography><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: repo[2].intro }}></div></>
           </CardContent>
            </Card>
  </Grid>
  
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} sx={{flexGrow:1}}>
           <Card  sx={{  display:'flex', bgcolor: "#f7f7f7"}} elevation={4} >
           <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' , borderRight:'2px black dashed'}}>
        <CardContent sx={{ flex: '1 0 auto' , display:'flex', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Typography component="div" sx={{fontWeight:'bold', textAlign:'center'}}>
          Education, Training & Experience
          </Typography>
        
          </CardContent>
         
          </Box>
          <CardHeader 
          subheaderTypographyProps={{fontSize: 14}}
          subheader= {<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: repo[2].education }}></div>} 
          />        
  </Card>
  </Grid>
  
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} sx={{flexGrow:1}}>
  <Card  sx={{  display:'flex', bgcolor: "#f7f7f7"}} elevation={4} >
           <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' , borderRight:'2px black dashed'}}>
        <CardContent sx={{ flex: '1 0 auto' , display:'flex', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Typography component="div" sx={{fontWeight:'bold', textAlign:'center'}}>
          Scope, Knowledge & Skills
          </Typography>
        
          </CardContent>
         
          </Box>
          <CardHeader 
         title= "Growth rate is 5% higher"
         subheaderTypographyProps={{fontSize: 15}}
          subheader= {<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: repo[2].scope }}></div>} 
          />
           </Card>
  </Grid>
  
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} sx={{flexGrow:1}} >
           <Card  sx={{  display:'flex', bgcolor: "#f7f7f7"}} elevation={4} >
           <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' , borderRight:'2px black dashed'}}>
        <CardContent sx={{ flex: '1 0 auto' , display:'flex', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Typography component="div" sx={{fontWeight:'bold', textAlign:'center'}}>
          Job Growth
          </Typography>
        
          </CardContent>
         
          </Box>
          <CardHeader 
          title="Approx"
          subheader={<><Typography>India : 56%</Typography><Divider orientation="horizontal" flexItem/>
          <Typography>Global: 63%</Typography></>}/>        
  </Card>
  </Grid>
  
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} sx={{flexGrow:1}} >
             <Card  sx={{  display:'flex', bgcolor: "#f7f7f7"}} elevation={4} >
           <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' , borderRight:'2px black dashed'}}>
        <CardContent sx={{ flex: '1 0 auto' , display:'flex', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Typography component="div" sx={{fontWeight:'bold', textAlign:'center'}}>
         Salary Range
          </Typography>
        
          </CardContent>
         
          </Box>
            <CardHeader 
          title="Details"
          subheader={<><Typography>India: 50Lpa</Typography><Divider orientation='horizontal' flexItem/>
          <Typography>Global: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: repo[2].salary_global }}></div> </Typography></>}/>
           </Card>
  </Grid>
  
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} sx={{ flexGrow:1}}>
  <Card  sx={{  display:'flex', bgcolor: "#f7f7f7"}} elevation={4} >
           <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' , borderRight:'2px black dashed'}}>
        <CardContent sx={{ flex: '1 0 auto' , display:'flex', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Typography component="div" sx={{fontWeight:'bold', textAlign:'center'}}>
         Work Styles
          </Typography>
        
          </CardContent>
         
          </Box>
            <CardHeader 
          
          subheader= {<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: repo[2].work_styles }}></div>} />
           </Card>
          </Grid>
  
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} sx={{flexGrow:1}}>
           <Card  sx={{ display:'flex', bgcolor: "#f7f7f7"}} elevation={4} >
           <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' , borderRight:'2px black dashed'}}>
        <CardContent sx={{ flex: '1 0 auto' , display:'flex', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Typography component="div" sx={{fontWeight:'bold', textAlign:'center'}}>
          Abilities
          </Typography>
        
          </CardContent>
         
          </Box>   
        <CardHeader 
        title="Abilities you should have:"
        subheader={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: repo[2].abilities }}></div>}/>
          </Card> 
          </Grid>
          

  </Fragment>
  </Grid>
        </Container>
  </>
```

I think its not reading repo[2].career
I am not sure.

Comment: Are you using id to fetch documents? Sounds unlikely. Also, use command line Mongo client and connect to your database to see if it's slow then as well or if it's your backend library which is causing delay. 2000 documents is very small and should be fast with or without indexes. Also, there is always an index on `_id` so it's not necessary to add one.

Comment: I am not using id to fetch documents. I am basically using the score to fetch documents. I am using mongodb compass connected with mongodb atlas.

Comment: Then the `_id` index cannot be used. You can only use indexes that relates to properties used to search for your document. So perhaps there is an expensive backend calculation taking time? Not familiar with compass and atlas but try to run the searches directly in the database to figure out if it's the database itself or some other layer that is causing the delay.

Comment: can you send the sample code that your using. ?

Comment: Reading from a collection with 2000 documents may not be a performance related issue - its a very small amount of data. You need to be clear about where the time is taking - querying from the database or fetching data from database through your NodeJS code to the front-end or showing that data in the front-end ui.

Comment: Sure I am updating the code which i am using.

Comment: I have updated the code can you please check?

Comment: Its the front end that causing delay while showing the data @prasad_. ::